# ID column in terra extract from SpatVector

Tags: r, terra

I am working in the `terra` package, and am using the function `extract` on a SpatRaster and SpatVector. The SpatRaster is a stack of five rasters with the names `"Elevation", "EVI", "LSTmean", "LSTsd", "population"`. The SpatVector is has borders of regions, with a region name in the variable `ID_2` and a variable called `inc` which is the incidence of a disease within that region.

Currently, I am using `extract`:

```
extracted <- extract(rasters, shapes, xy = TRUE)
```

which gives the columns `"ID", "Elevation", "EVI", "LSTmean", "LSTsd", "population", "x", "y"`. I am then converting the shapefile into a `data.frame`, creating an ID variable then merging back in:

```
shapes_df <- as.data.frame(shapes)
shapes_df$ID <- seq_len(nrow(shapes_df))
shapes_df <- shapes_df[, c("ID", "ID_2", "inc")]
full_df <- merge(shapes_df, extracted, by = "ID", all = TRUE)
```

Is there a way that I can do this within the `extract` function, so that I am not creating an `ID` variable and messing around with merges?

Comment: as I read `?terra::extract, ID = TRUE`, will give you ID of `y`, i.e. your `shapes`, though from above perhaps your `shapes` don't have ID, and ID = TRUE just says use the ID found in y, rather than create one, though here I could be wrong, but absent a y$ID, then what?